# How to set the id attribute of a HTML element dynamically with angularjs (1.x)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, string-concatenation

Provided an HTML element of type `div`, how to set the value of its `id` attribute, which is the concatenation of a scope variable and a string ?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

`ngAttr` directive can totally be of help here, as introduced in the official documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

For instance, to set the `id` attribute value of a `div` element, so that it contains an index, a view fragment might contain

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ 'object-' + myScopeObject.index }}"></div>
```

which would get interpolated to

```
<div id="object-1"></div>
```

Comment: Where does `myScopeObject` come from? Where would I define it?

Comment: @JanAagaard Let us assume `myScopeObject` is a property of a `scope` object exposed using a controller. Please see also https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller. Is that clear enough for you or shall I elaborate further?

Comment: i did ng-attr-id="{{ 'Panel' + file.Id }}" but it does not generate id="Panel12312" for me :(

Comment: Aren't the following two identical in behavior: `<div id="{{ 'object' + index }}">` and `<div ng-attr-id="{{ 'object' + index }}">` ? The docs seem to say prepending `ng-attr-` is to help out for cases where the element is something non-standard, like not a `<div>`. Am I reading the docs right?

Comment: Hi please check this is not working for me
ng-attr-id="{{'note_'+Note.NoteId}}"

Comment: @broc.seib using nd-attr is not only about standard. This is good practice because HTML interpreter can assign id to the element before angular gets loaded. And ng-attr ensures to assign id to the element only when angular gets loaded. same is the case for ng-src in <img> tag.

Comment: This answer is wrong. @broc.seib is right, according to the article linked to in this answer there are few situations where `ng-attr-` is necessary; `id` is not one of them.

Answer (score 81):

This thing worked for me pretty well:

`<div id="{{ 'object-' + $index }}"></div>`

Comment: Time flies and perhaps, the most intuitive syntax now just works as expected. I remember having some issues while iterating over a list.

Comment: This will work correct in 90% of cases but you may sometimes get errors which are hard to debug. You should use ng-attr-id instead.

Comment: `ng-attr-id` is advantageous in 0% of situations. No examples can be provided, because there are none.

Comment: The `ng-attr-id` method is to ensure that the raw ng expression is never rendered in a valid HTML attribute (e.g. `id`, `label`, etc). This is to stop any downstream usage reading ng 'junk' (e.g. before render is complete, or after a js crash)

Answer (score 61):

In case you came to this question but related to newer **Angular version >= 2.0**.

```
<div [id]="element.id"></div>
```

Comment: That is not useful, the question is in context of AngularJS

Comment: I agree; it’s only going to be useful to those members that find it useful.

Comment: Some members still click on Angularjs links even though they are searching for Angular links. It's a bit confusing and errors will continue to happen.

Comment: Be careful this is for Angular  versions 2 or greater, Agree on this is out of context regarding the question, but the comment is very clear when saying which version of angular is applicable this approach

Comment: Google doesn't seem to care much about the difference between AngularJS and Angular 2. This is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

A more elegant way I found to achieve this behaviour is simply:

```
<div id="{{ 'object-' + myScopeObject.index }}"></div>
```

For my implementation I wanted each input element in a ng-repeat to each have a unique id to associate the label with. So for an array of objects contained inside myScopeObjects one could do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in myScopeObject">
    <input id="{{object.name + 'Checkbox'}}" type="checkbox">
    <label for="{{object.name + 'Checkbox'}}">{{object.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Being able to generate unique ids on the fly can be pretty useful when dynamically adding content like this.

Comment: I think this approach has issues. I am initializing the angular binding after the page is loaded. Now at times the div fails to load properly which I guess is because of clash of id of different div.

Comment: Interesting. If you could reproduce your behavior in a plunker example I would be happy to check it out. Does using 'ng-attr-id=' work and just using 'id=' not?

Answer (score 10):

You could just simply do the following

In your js

```
$scope.id = 0;
```

In your template

```
<div id="number-{{$scope.id}}"></div>
```

which will render

```
<div id="number-0"></div>
```

It is not necessary to concatenate inside double curly brackets.

Answer (score 6):

Just `<input id="field_name_{{$index}}" />`

Comment: Why a $ in front of index?

Comment: I think it is probably because that is supposed to be in a ng-repeat?

Comment: Exact . @Pipo you should, may be, check here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat :)

Answer (score -1):

If you use this syntax:

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ 'object-' + myScopeObject.index }}"></div>
```

Angular will render something like:

```
 <div ng-id="object-1"></div>
```

However this syntax:

```
<div id="{{ 'object-' + $index }}"></div>
```

will generate something like:

```
<div id="object-1"></div>
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to say?

Comment: Why should `ng-attr-id` create `ng-id`..? that's wrong. I wonder who upvotes this