# $anchorScroll to class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, anchor-scroll

In my web application, I let the user use the arrow keys to go up and down a large list set up using `ng-repeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="vpn in vpns 
          | orderBy: 'Title' 
          | customFilter:searchString" 
          ng-class="{'highlight': $index == focusIndex }">
```

the current `<li>` gets class highlight.  I'd also like to scroll the page to their current selection, as each `<li>` is large, and the page only can show about 3 at a time.  I know i can use `$location` and `$anchorScroll` to scroll to an id via the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24anchorScroll) but I can't figure out how to scroll to a class, or to use some sort of `ng-id` similar to ng-class (only one element will be highlighted at a time).

If anyone could offer me a few pointers that would be great.  Thankyou!

Comment: I know it's a bit ttlate but here you may have your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angular-js