# How to set value for dir-Attribute via AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to set the direction of the `body`-element depending on some logic inside the controller.

So if a language file has a certain value, i want to change from "ltr" to "rtl".

I know there is a way of [setting HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angular-js) via `ng-attr-`, but it's not working for `dir`.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7370/) to show my problem. The question is:

> How can I set the dir-attribute via the controller?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-attr-dir="{{direct}}">   
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.direct = "rtl";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `dir`, instead of `ng-attr-dir`.

```
<div dir="{{direct}}">
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7371/)**

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished with a trivial directive:

```
myApp.directive("myDir", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe("myDir", function(newval) {
                if( newval ) {
                    elem.attr("dir", newval);
                }
                else {
                    elem.removeAttr("dir");
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Use it as:

```
<div my-dir="{{direct}}">
```

A forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34ch4qef/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use  inline `style="direction:{{direct}}"`  instead .

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7373/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an Angular version the actually supports `ngAttr` ;) 1.0 doesn't.