# Create custom input directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-directive

I would like to create a custom input that looks like that:

```
<my-input ng-model="aScopeProperty" placeholder="Enter text" 
data-title="This is my title"></my-input>
```

my-input should receive any property that regular input can get (like placeholder and etc...).

the output should be like this (myInputTemplate.html):

```
<div class="my-input">
    {{title}}           
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" />    
</div>
```

I created a directive:

```
myApp.directive('myInput', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: '/myInput/myInputTemplate.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            text: '=ngModel',
            title: '=title'
        },            
    }
```

});

the ng-model is bindded ok now,
**my question** is:
How can I pass the attributes (like placeholder and etc) from my-input to the inside input?

I think that I approached it the wrong way, maybe I need to do it like that:

```
  <input my-input ng-model="aScopeProperty" placeholder="Enter text" 
   data-title="This is my title"></input>
```

and to wrap the input with:

```
 <div class="my-input">
    {{title}}  
    <here will be the original input> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

directive call should be like

```
<my-input ng-model="aScopeProperty" placeholder="'Enter text'" title="'This is my title'"></my-input>
```

note the `placeholder="'Enter text'"` `Enter text` with in `quotes (')`, this indicate these values are string so angular will not search for `scope` variable.

and in the directive

```
myApp.directive('myInput', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      templateUrl: '/myInput/myInputTemplate.html',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
          text: '=ngModel',
          title: '=title',
          placeholder : '=placeholder'
      },            
  }
});
```

and the template

```
<div class="my-input">
    {{title}}           
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" />    
</div>
```

here is the [demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6ma6EDd5dme2pZzuCgRR?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but "placeholder" was just an example, today is "placeholder" tomorrow it will be another attribute, can I make it generic?

Comment: then you need to add that attribute as above :)

Comment: I think that I approached it the wrong way, maybe I need to do it like that:

      <input my-input ng-model="aScopeProperty" placeholder="Enter text" 
data-title="This is my title"></input>

and to wrap the input with: 
 <div class="my-input">
    {{title}}  
    <here will be the original input> 
</div>

Comment: then what is the different between these 2 ?

Comment: I edited my question...
the difference is that in the second approach I wrap the original input. 
in the first I created new input in the directive...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-attr` as the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-attr-placeholder="{{placeholder}}"/>
```

And send placeholder as attribute in your scope as the following:

```
scope: {
      text: '=ngModel',
      title: '=title',
      placeholder : '=placeholder'
  }
```

I recommend to read about [ng-attr-attrName](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and this [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23655154/2791480).

**Dynamic attributes**

Read my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799345/send-array-of-attributes-to-directive/27799686#27799686), and accepted answer.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but "placeholder" was just an example, today is "placeholder" tomorrow it will be another attribute, can I make it generic? that all the attributes will go to the input?

Comment: @ShlomiAharoni I updated my answer, I asked your question but with another way :)

Answer (score 0):

The second approach succeeded!

final code:

```
<input my-input ng-model="aScopeProperty" placeholder="Enter text" 
data-title="This is my title">
```

The Directive:

```
app.directive('myInput', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        title: '=title'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
        var wrap = angular.element('<div class="my-input-wrapper" />');
        $element.addClass('form-control').removeAttr('my-input');
        wrap.insertBefore($element);
        $element.appendTo(wrap);
        if ($scope.title) {
            var title = angular.element('<span class="my-title">' + $scope.title + '</span>');
            title.appendTo(wrap);
        }
    },
}
```

});

I even created my first Plunker for it, unfortunately, the Plunker don't works because it doesn't recognize: insertBefore and appendTo

http://plnkr.co/edit/XnFM75vOBg4ifHUQzGOt?p=preview