# send array of attributes to directive

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I read about `ng-attr` for [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), but I want to send array of attributes to directive as example:

```
<myElement attributes="attributes"></myElement>
```

And my directive as example:

```
myApp.directive('myElement', function(){
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<div>' + 
              '<!-- I want to add this attributes on the div element>' + 
              '</div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        attributes: '=attributes'
    },            
  }
});
```

And the attributes is in controller as the following:

```
$scope.attributes = {"class": "test", "id": "test", "style": "color: 'red'"}
```

So, How can I set array of attributes in element in directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In link function of your directive

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs){
     var templateElement = angular.element(element[0].firstChild) //this is you template div el.
      angular.forEach(scope.attributes, function(value, key){
           //if you want to set the root element
           attrs.$set(key, value)
           //if you want to set template root div
          templateElement.attr(key, value)
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<my-element attributes="attributes"></my-element>
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('myElement', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: 'ngModel',
                template: '<div class="{{attributes.class}}" id="{{attributes.id}}" style="{{attributes.style}}">' +
                'I want to add this attributes on the div element' +
                '</div>',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    attributes: '=attributes'
                }
            }
        });
```

controller:

```
$scope.attributes = {"class": "test", "id": "test", "style": "color: red"};
```