# scope in angular and applied css class only on first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm calling js function every 2 seconds where on certain condition I want to update div on the view.

```
 <div id="ball_{{ballIndex}}">{{ball}}</div>
```

on ng controller

```
       var myCounter = 0;

        var interval = $interval(function () {
            if (myCounter <= 35) {
                myCounter ++;
                DoSomething();
            } else {
                //
            }
        }, 1500);

        function setCurrentBallEffect() {
            $('#ball_' + myCounter).addClass('magictime puffIn');                
        }

        function DoSomething() {
            if (myCounter == 0) {
                $scope.ballIndex = 1;
            } else {
                $scope.ballIndex = myCounter;
            }
        }
```

using this code only first div in iteration is applied with class magictime puffIn. When I hardcode div id's on the view side like `<div id="ball_1">1</div>` `<div id="ball_2">2</div>` .. applied css class work on each div. What I'm doing wrong?

Update:
Tried with

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ 'ball_' + ballIndex }}"> </div>
```

but problem is still present.

Comment: answered in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angular-js). It's the same issue as why you can't write `<a href="{{ngValue}}">` but have to use `<a ng-href="{{ngValue}}">`

Comment: thanks but this did not help, problem is still present.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood your question entirely. When is the function `setCurrentBallEffect()` ever called? Perhaps provide more code, especially the part where the `setCurrentBallEffect()` function is called.

Answer (score 0):

At first you must define

```
var myCounter =0;
```

I don't understand ball

you must defined it like this :

```
$scope.ball=0;
```

I Change view like this

```
<div id="ball_{{ballIndex}}">{{ballIndex}}</div>
```

and your javascript changed like this:

```
var poolCounter = 0;
    var myCounter = 0;

    var interval = $interval(function () {
        if (myCounter <= 35) {
            myCounter++;
            DoSomething();
        } else {
            //
        }
    }, 1500);

    function setCurrentBallEffect() {
        $('#ball_' + myCounter).addClass('magictime puffIn');
    }

    function DoSomething() {
        if (myCounter == 0) {
            $scope.ballIndex = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.ballIndex = myCounter;
        }
    }
```