# Give dynamic id Angular2 Binds

Tags: javascript, angular

My JavaScript:

```
 this.items = [
            {name: 'Amsterdam1', id: '1'},
            {name: 'Amsterdam2', id: '2'},
            {name: 'Amsterdam3', id: '3'}
        ];
```

My HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#item of items" id={{item.id}}>
    {{ item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to assign a dynamic id to each element, but can't get it to work. The name is showing up but the id is not.

Comment: I think you need to wrap the id value in quotes. `id="{{item.id}}"`

Comment: Tried that previously, it did not work.

Comment: A quick search got me this: [How to set the id attribute of a HTML element dynamically with Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23655154/689044)

Comment: @MichaelEarls Yes in Angular 1, but I am using Angular2.

Answer (score 50):

the way you said works, Angular 2.0.0.beta.8.

in this case you can use for example:

- `[id]="item.id"`
- `[attr.id]="item.id"`
- `id={{item.id}}`

  ```
       <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#item of items" #elem [id]="item.id">
          {{ item.name}} ID: {{elem.id}}
        </li>
       </ul>

       <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#item of items" #elem [attr.id]="item.id">
          {{ item.name}} ID: {{elem.id}}
        </li>
       </ul>

       <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#item of items" #elem id={{item.id}}>
          {{ item.name}} ID: {{elem.id}}
        </li>
       </ul>
  ```

### <kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9CyWeUtoVM8R88x287QN?p=preview)</kbd>

You can look here for more information in Template syntax.

https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet

Answer (score 14):

All the methods provided by @AngelAngel are correct but just to explain why to use `[attr.id]` posted as answer.

Angular by default uses `property binding`. To tell Angular explicitly to use attribute binding, we use instead:

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#item of items" #elem [attr.id]="item.id">
        {{ item.name}} ID: {{elem.id}}
      </li>
     </ul>
```

With `attr.id` you have to explicitly opt in to attribute binding because attribute binding is expensive. Attributes are reflected in the DOM and changes require for example to check if CSS selectors are registered that match with this attribute set. Property binding is JS only and cheap, therefore the default.

Answer (score 5):

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="#item of items" attr.id={{item.name}}>
  {{ item.name}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

This should work (worked for me on angular2).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I can use [attr.id] tag on the 'li' tag.

Comment: you can use comment instead of answer for this line