# Dynamically assign element id inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to give a dynamically assigned id for a div inside a *ngFor. I would like the divs to be called 'wave1, wave2, wave3' etc.

```html
<li *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
    <div id="wave{{i}}"></div>
</li>
```

However, this throws the following error:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
> '#wave[object Object]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Can you add code where you use `'#wave...`? Seems it's clear that you concat object with string

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34568497, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36051195

Comment: angular 2 is the version

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `{{ 'wave' + i }}` instead of `wave{{i}}`. Make it as Angular Experession. This is the full `ngFor`:

```
<li *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
     <div id="{{ 'wave' + i }}"></div>
</li>
```

It works and creates the `div` with the correct `id`

```
document.getElementById("wave1")
```

Output will be like this:

```
<div id=​"wave1">​wave1​</div>
```

but remember your code will start from `wave0` as `i = index` starts from 0.

Comment: That's great for assigning the id, but how do you then reference the Id dynamically in your html?  I am trying to implement validation against a field with a dynamically assigned Id.  I need to be able to say something like *ngIf="'controlName' + index.invalid".

Answer (score 13):

What you have is correct and should work in angular 4/5. Are you maybe using a really old, pre-release angular 2 version?

Here is a stackblitz with your code and the code below, both working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khur4v?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

You can also do it that way, which is the preferred way

```
<li *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
    <div [attr.id]="'wave' + i">{{episode.name}}</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to define `i`

```js
<li *ngFor="let episode of episodes">
    <div id="wave{{episode}}">{{episode}}</div>
</li>
```

**EDIT: in case episodes is a list of objects**

```js
<li *ngFor="let episode of episodes">
    <div id="wave{{episodes.indexOf(episode)}}">{{episode.name}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: That won't work if `episodes` is a list of objects, which it probably is in the OP's example

Comment: True, let me modify the example

Answer (score 2):

For me it works if I add Singlequotes. Otherwise Angular detects a var.

```
<li *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
    <div id="'wave' + i"></div>
</li>
```