# Chrome is showing the angular expression instead of value. Firefox displays the correct value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Showing AngularJS expression in DOM instead of value in chrome browser but it showing correct value in Firefox.

In Chrome it shows like:

```
<div id="{profile.id}" data-id="{{profile.id}}">Some Text</div>
```

In Firefox it displays correctly:

```
<div id="1234" data-id="1234">Some Text</div>
```

How do I solve this for Chrome?

Comment: What's the contents of your html file? (For that line)

Comment: Try Ctrl + Shift + R for Chrome to clear the cache?

Comment: obviously angular doesn't load in your chrome. make sure its loaded. another possibility is that you have many dom elements with the same id. Are you sure the id="1234" is unique to that element? Chrome could get the last one, firefox the first one and make a mess

Comment: You can use ng-attr-id in place of id to set id dynamically .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angular-js .